# How to solve Memory leakage in windows multiple threading application

Tags: c#, .net

Actually I am working on real-time application with multiple threads.

While I am running my application memory is 65 Mb and if I open a child MDI form then memory increases to 85mb but if I close the child window then memory will still remains at 85mb.

I have used Dispose and I've already tried with GC.Collect(), but none of these solve my problems,
so I am little bit confused regarding this issue.

Can you please guide me regarding this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly post some code snippet. There might be something you are overlooking.

Comment: Do you detach event handlers as needed?

Comment: How are you going about setting the MDIParent/Showing the child window? Can you post some code?

Comment: This is normal.  Minimize your main window for a possible quick fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a good memory profiler.

There are a bunch of options:

- [RedGates's ANTS memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/)
- [Scitech's .NET memory profiler](http://memprofiler.com/)
- [CLR Profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLR_Profiler) (pre .NET 4.0)
- and more.

Many cost money (except CLR Profiler) but usually have trial versions.

After you start your app (with the profiler attached), you need to take snapshots of the memory before the leak and after and compare them to see what is staying around.

It's hard to say what the problem might be in your case, since there are many things that could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you used some global delegate references in your child MDI form?

Answer (score 0):

Does the memory increase every time you open a new child window? If so, open and close several of these and then attach to the process using windbg.

After loading sos, you can use the !dumpheap command to get an idea of where the memory leak might be and then use gcroot to find where the leaked memory's is rooted.

This blog might help:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx

Btw, how are you writing a "real-time application" in c#?

Answer (score 0):

The task manager memory number is not always as sharp as it would be, however this small trick can cheat that number... Not meant for production.

```
public static void RefreshMemory() {
    try {
        Process curProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        curProc.MaxWorkingSet = curProc.MaxWorkingSet;
    } catch {
        // Handle the exception
    }
}
```